# integer in C Get Random value

Tags: c, bluez

i want write program in C via bluez API

I have used this [site](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html) for tutorial :

and this is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    int res_scan=NULL;
    int count;
    inquiry_info *device_info=NULL;
    res_scan = hci_inquiry(dev_id,3,255,NULL,&device_info,IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH);
    printf("%i\n",res_scan);
    for(count = 0;count < res_scan;count++)
    {
        char *name;
        printf("count Before : %i\n",count);
        ba2str(&(device_info+count)->bdaddr,&name);
        printf("count After : %i\n",count);

        printf("%s\n",&name);
    }



}
```

and out console :

```
2
count Before : 0
count After : 1111833143
00:17:EB:5D:1B:86
```

why `count` value after `ba2str(&(device_info+count)->bdaddr,&name);` get random value ?

in that source i linked this issue wont occur !?

Comment: You didn't allocate memory for `name`...

Comment: Did you care about what `ba2str` could do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need allocate memory before pass the variable as reference, and the best option is to do that out of the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    int res_scan=NULL;
    int count;
    char *name = (char *) malloc(248*sizeof(char));
    inquiry_info *device_info=NULL;
    res_scan = hci_inquiry(dev_id,3,255,NULL,&device_info,IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH);
    printf("%i\n",res_scan);
    for(count = 0;count < res_scan;count++)
    {
        printf("count Before : %i\n",count);
        ba2str(&(device_info+count)->bdaddr,name);
        printf("count After : %i\n",count);

        printf("%s\n",name);
    }

 free(name);

}
```

doing that your code will be faster because you will allocate memory only one time.

Comment: remember to clear with `memset`before using `ba2str`

Comment: Why allocate name on the heap?

Comment: I imagine the function ba2str try write something on the variable name, so you will need allocate it, but it could be used char name[248] too, but always out of the loop.

Answer (score 5):

instead of

```
char *name;
...
printf("%s\n",&name);
```

use

```
char name[248] = { 0 };
...
printf("%s\n",name);
```

Comment: and probably also plain `name` instead of `&name`

Comment: @JensGustedt no `ba2str` requires a pointer for both arguments.

Comment: yes, an array in that context decays to a pointer. Or do you mean pointer to pointer? It is definitively wrong for the `printf` call.